# How to control the number of stacked bars through single select widget in python bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, widget, visualization, bokeh

I have created a vertical stacked bar chart using python bokeh on an input dataset df using the following code -

```
print(df.head())

  YearMonth         A         B         C         D         E
0    Jan'18  1587.816  1586.544   856.000  1136.464  1615.360
1    Feb'18  2083.024  1847.808  1036.000  1284.016  2037.872
2    Mar'18  2193.420  1850.524  1180.000  1376.028  2076.464
3    Apr'18  2083.812  1811.636  1192.028  1412.028  2104.588
4    May'18  2379.976  2091.536  1452.000  1464.432  2400.876
```

Stacked Bar Chart Code -

```
products = ['python', 'pypy', 'jython']
customers = ['Cust 1', 'Cust 2']
colours = ['red', 'blue']
data = {
    'products': products,
    'Cust 1': [200, 850, 400],
    'Cust 2': [600, 620, 550],
    'Retail 1' : [100, 200, 300],
    'Retail 2' : [400,500,600]
}


source = ColumnDataSource(data)
# Set up widgets
select=Select(options=['customers','retailers'],value='customers')
def make_plot() :
    p=figure()
    #p.title.text=select.value
    if select.value=='customers' :
        customers=['cust 1','cust 2']
    else :
        customers=['Retail 1','Retail 2']   
    p.hbar_stack(customers, y='products', height=0.5, source=source, color=colours)
    return p



layout = column(select, make_plot())           

# Set up callbacks
def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    p = make_plot()    # make a new plot
    layout.children[1] = p


select.on_change('value', update_data)

# # Set up layouts and add to document
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Now I want to limit the number of segments(ie.stacked bars) by using a widget (preferrably by a single select widget). Can anyone please guide me how can i achieve using bokeh serve functionality. I don't want to use Javascript call back function.

Answer (score 0):

This would take some non-trivial work to make happen. The `vbar_stack` method is a convenience function that actually creates *multiple glyph renderers*, one for each "row" in the *initial* stacking. What's more the renderers are all inter-related to one another, via the `Stack` transform that stacks all the previous renderers at each step. So there is not really any simple way to change the number of rows that are stacked after the fact. So much so that I would suggest simply deleting and re-creating the entire plot in each callback. (I would not normally recommend this approach, but this situation is one of the few exceptions.)

Since you have not given complete code or even mentioned what widget you want to use, all I can provide is a high level sketch of the code. Here is a complete example that updates a plot based on select widget:

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

select = Select(options=["1", "2", "3", "4"], value="1")

def make_plot():
    p = figure()
    p.circle(x=[0,2], y=[0, 5], size=15)
    p.circle(x=1, y=float(select.value), color="red", size=15)
    return p

layout = column(select, make_plot())

def update(attr, old, new):
    p = make_plot()    # make a new plot
    layout.children[1] = p  # replace the old plot

select.on_change('value', update)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Note I have changed your `show` call to `curdoc().add_root` since it is never useful to call `show` in a Bokeh server application. You might want to refer to and study the User Guide chapter [Running a Bokeh Server](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) for background information, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, @bigreddot. I am still not able to come up with the complete code. I want to use a single select dropdown widget.

Comment: I've made it a complete (generic) example. I can't do any more, e.g. I can't write `make_plot` for you since you are the only person who knows what it needs to do.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation,@bigreddot. I have mentioned my exact code in the original post above. However, its still not working for me. On running the code, nothing is displayed at first. Can you please have a look. Really appreciate your help here !

Comment: You have a missing import. You can see the error in the console when you run `bokeh serve`.

Comment: Just for simplicity, I have missed import libraries statement. Assuming all the libraries are imported, still the code is not working

Comment: Well, I can't run it to investigate and help until is is complete and runnable. The guidance on asking questions on SO is always to provide a complete, minimal, reproducing example.